# Redux connect works but now for all properties from the state

Tags: reactjs, redux

My problem is that `props.val` works as it should, but `props.name` does not. Can anyone help me figure out why?

```jsx
import Device from "../Device/Device";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const dummy = props => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Device
        name={props.name[0]}
        value={props.val[0]}
      />
      <Device name={props.name[1]} value={props.val[1]} />
      <Device name={props.name[2]} value={props.val[2]} />
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    val: state.msgValue,
    name: state.name
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(dummy);
```

In redux devtools, `state` looks like this:

```js
state = {
  msgValue: [23, 34, 45],
  name: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
};
```

Edit: I have dispatched action on the wrong place and when I dispatched it in the right place, everything was okay.

Comment: What's the result of `console.log(props)` after this line: `const dummy = props => {`

Comment: Are you sure? If yes what’s the error?

Comment: Object with name and val arrays that are exactly the same as the state above.

Comment: whats the error showing on console?

Comment: If there is any error in your code. it's not in what you have shown to us. please provide more details

Comment: There is no error. It  gives me two objects, first contains empty name array and val array that has numbers in it, and the second object contains name and val arrays that contains items that it should contain.

Comment: Ok, What's the result of `console.log(state)` after this line:  `const mapStateToProps = state => {` ?

Comment: ...................................

Comment: what are these dots ?

Comment: I get several objects, as many action creators I have... the last object is when the whole state is full and contain val and name arrays with values in it like state I posted in original question.

Comment: Do you consider accepting the answer if it resolves your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I could see in your code is that accessing array with index 3. The state array length is only 3 but you are accessing index 3 element which doesn’t exist

So remove below code from your component

```
  <Device name={props.name[3]} value={props.val[3]} />
```

Also do this conditional check

```
    {Array.isArray(props.name) && Array.isArray(props.val) && props.name.length && props.val.length && (
    <div className="container"> <Device
        name={props.name[0]}
        value={props.val[0]}
      />
      <Device name={props.name[1]} value={props.val[1]} />
      <Device name={props.name[2]} value={props.val[2]} />
      </div>
     )}
```

Also you make sure you access only available index

Comment: There are more components, i deleted many of them to make it more readable ,there is that item in the state. My bad.